# java null pointer exception with static array

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-members, static-array

I got a null pointer exception when accessing a static array from a static member method. 
The exception is thrown when i call setData(x, y, z) from a thread. When I debugged it I found out data[0] is null when i try to write to it. I just don't understand how it can be null

```
public class dataContainer 
{
    private static final short nrOfDataElements = ids.total_ids;
    private static regularDataElement[] data = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];


    public static synchronized void getData(final short i, regularDataElement r)
    {
        if ( (i >= 0) && (i < nrOfDataElements) )
            r.set(data[i].getTimestamp(), data[i].getValue());  
    }          

    public static synchronized void setData(short i, double ts, long val)
    {
        if ( (i >= 0) && (i < nrOfDataElements) )
            data[i].set(ts, val); //<<-------null pointer exception, debugging showed data[i] == null, (with i = 0 and nrOfDataElements = 12)
    }
}
```

and

```
public class regularDataElement 
{
    regularDataElement()
    {
        set(0, 0);
    }

    public void set(double _ts, long _val)
    {
        System.out.println(this.ts + " " + _ts + " " + this.val + " " + _val); System.out.flush();
        this.ts = _ts;
        this.val = _val;    
    }

    public double getTimestamp()
    {
        return this.ts;
    }

    public long getValue()
    {
        return this.val;
    }

    private double ts;
    private long val;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `private static regularDataElement[] data = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];` initializes `data` with an array the size of `nrOfDataElements`. It does **not** initialize each element in this array. I.e., all the elements are null.

If you wish to initialize the elements, you should do so yourself. E.g., you could add a static block to handle this:

```
static regularDataElement[] data = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfDataElements; ++i) {
        data[i] = new regularDataElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that totally did the trick. i assumed the memory for the array elements would be allocated implicitly, like in c++. the static scope is great, didn't know this was possible, thx :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever initialize the `data` array?

```
private static regularDataElement[] data = 
    new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];
```

will create an array full of `null` objects of size `nrOfDataElements`.  It won't actually initialize any elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be allocating memory for `data[i]`, which is why you're getting the NPE.

Allocating memory for the array itself is not enough. You need to allocate memory for each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrOfDataElements; ++i) {
   data[i] = new regularDataElement(...);
}
```

(Replace `...` with the actual arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

You never actually create any objects. You must add somewhere:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = new regularDataElement();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an `Object` array in `Java`, like `data` in your code, all elements are by default set to `null`.

So, you need to populate the `data` array first, before being able to call any methods against its elements.

Assuming that the `regularDataElement` class has a no-args (i.e., no parameters) constructor, you could do

```
static regularDataElement[] data = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];

static
{
    for (int i=0; i<nrOfDataElements; i++)
    {
        data[i] = new regularDataElement();
    }
}
```

Of course, you could have a separate method to initialize the array, e.g.

```
static regularDataElement[] initialize(int nrOfDataElements)
{
    regularDataElement[] elements = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];

    for (int i=0; i<nrOfDataElements; i++)
    {
        elements[i] = new regularDataElement();
    }

    return elements;
}
```

and then call that method to create and initialize the data array, replacing the statement

```
static regularDataElement[] data = new regularDataElement[nrOfDataElements];
```

with

```
static regularDataElement[] data = initialize(nrOfDataElements);
```

Also, as a matter of following established coding conventions, you should name your classes starting with a capital letter, i.e. use `RegularDataElement` instead of `regularDataElement`.